# Bootstrap 3 modal repeating content - how to empty the previous modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 to load external content into modals but the content keeps repeating.  I understand that I need to empty the previous modal, but due to my poor jQUery skills I am unsure how I would do this, can someone provide me with a working version of this script?

```
$(function() {
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
if (!$this.data('isloaded')) {
    if(remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
        $this.data('isloaded', true)
    }
}
});
});
```

I have tried several options that I found both here and on other forums but I just can't get it right :( 
Anyone....?

Comment: Here is a link that might prove useful
http://plnkr.co/edit/HWSgSw?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **if(remote) statement** is not returning true ever.

Also, the `.load()` isn't working in the fiddle, so I modified the code in the fiddle to load divs `#contact-modal` and `#faq-modal` that have the same HTML in them as your remote html.

[**Fork of your JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/9m6tC/)

### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $remote = $( $this.data('load-remote') );
        var $target = $( $this.data('remote-target') );

        // Load HTML into modal
        $target.html( $remote.html() );
    });
});
```

To empty something that already has stuff in it before you `.load()` it with something you should be able to do something like this:

```
$target.empty();
$target.load(remote);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but a little bit too effective. Once I have selected (displayed) the content of each external modal once they will not load again.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tomtom/uJhv3/1/
I don't know this fiddle isn't pulling the content since it works locally for me.. but there is an exact copy of my code

Comment: @no0ne .load() isn't working in the JSFiddle but I added the html to the page to test the rest. http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/9m6tC/